# Codeigniter Session - Access Userdata value for all users from DB

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using Codeigniter's Session class to store session values in the database. Contained within the `userdata` field is the user's username and other values.

I want to get the `username` from each `userdata` field where the `lastactivity` is >= let's say 5 minutes.

The only way I can think to accomplish this is:

- search for users active in last 5 minutes
- get the userdata for each row returned
- unserialise userdata
- extract username

However this seems like the long way. Is there a cleaner/better way to do this?

Comment: Do u want to store all username etc. data from your database whose lastactivity > x to CI Session ?

Comment: The userdata field in the DB will contain a few different values, I just need to extract one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$query = $this->db->select('user_data')->get('ci_sessions');

$user = array(); /* array to store the user data we fetch */

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $udata = unserialize($row->user_data);

    /* put data in array using username as key */
    $user[$udata['user_name']] = $udata['user_role']; 
}
```

from the result array, u can fetch needed information.

Comment: That's identical to the solution I listed and said I was trying to avoid if possible. I realise it may be necessary but only as a last resort.